# GraalVM build is failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to build native image of my SpringBoot 3 app with generated configuration from agent of native-image-agent

My steps I currently do:

- Building of .jar: *mvn -DskipTests spring-boot:run* with jvmArgs which provided in maven configuration:

```
<jvmArguments>
    -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=target/native-image
</jvmArguments>
```

- Next step is I remove jvmArgument which builds configuration and run command which builds native image: *mvn -DskipTests -Pnative clean package*

In generated reflect-config.json of the first step I can find configuration for HikariConfig class and method setConnectionTimeout(long ms), but when I try to run generated in second step native image I can see this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDataSource': Runtime reflection is not supported for public void com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(long)
```

Seems that this configuration is not loaded during native image build.
Probably I should set some config path variable or put config to some folder, could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration files generated by the Tracing Agent must be put under `META-INF/native-image` (as described [here](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/#tracing-agent)).

Your project structure should look like this:

```
Project
|__src
   |__main
      |__java
      |__resources
         |__META-INF
            |__native-image <-- Put the configuration files in this folder
```

Then start the native image build again:  `mvn -DskipTests -Pnative clean package`

If you run the binary, the exception should be gone.